# How to know that a control is busy performing any task in a window application?

Tags: c#, windows

I am  working on a window based application in C# and running a timer which is running on Main MDI Parent control from where many child controls are open/edited/closed. Now, I would like to know that on timer code that whether the whole application is busy or idle. If any control is performing any task like accessing data from database, or executing insert query or deleting data etc., then I should know as Application is busy and if not the Application is idle.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What kind of timer you are using? `System.Windows.Forms.Timer`, `System.Threading.Timer` or `System.Timers.Timer`?

Answer (score 0):

You should put all your time consuming task in background worker (`BackgroundWorker`) class. So that you can continuously monitor, get progress and exit if needed without any impact on the UI.

Here is the link for sample app,

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx

Comment: Hi @MD.Unicorn, I am using System.Windows.Forms.Timer and here I like to know this as I have implemented an Auto Log Out feature which flashes a warning message if the application is idle for specific time like 50 minutes and then it closes all the opened child controls. after that it brings the user on log in window.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Windows Forms Timer (`System.Windows.Forms.Timer`) then the timer code (`Tick` event) never is executed when the UI thread is busy, unless someone calls `Application.DoEvents()` in the middle of something. But if you have background workers or other kind of threads that perform some tasks, then there is no explicit way to know that the other threads are busy doing something.

You should use [Thread Synchronization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173179.aspx) mechanisms to ensure that your don't mess with something in your timer event. You can also use some guard variables. It is better to consider some architectural fix.

**EDIT:**
You cannot check for application idleness in a timer. What if an operation started and finished in a fraction of a second before your timer notices?

The best way is to have a global `lastOperationTime` variable, and set it to `DateTime.Now` every time an action is taken. Then use a timer to check the time passed from `lastOperationTime`:

```
void idleTimer_Tick (object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if ((DateTime.Now - lastOperationTime).TotalMinutes > 50)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

The hardest part is how to inject a line of code in every method that does some useful operation! If you have a good framework with properly organized base classes, there might be specific (finite) points that you should put the code to update `lastOperationTime`.